# How to understand a before-after effect in a longitudinal medical dataset

Tags: r, regression, time-series, clinical-trials

I am after some suggestions on what statistical analysis I can perform to show a before-and-after effect in a longitudinal electronic healthcare record (EHR). I have N number of EHRs, of varying sizes/time-spans. Each record has a history of recurrent disease records (for the one disease). To see whether a particular drug has had an effect on the disease outcome (duration before the next relapse), I have used time-gap recurrent cox regression.

However, I would now like to see whether the disease outcome (a series of remissions into relapses, good = long durations in between, bad = short durations in between) is immediately clear from the first prescription of a particular drug. In my head I imagine, taking all of the records (of vary time-span sizes -- very important to remember), and adjusting so every record overlaps when the drug of interest is first prescribed. Y axis is disease prevalence or risk, and x axis is time. From before the initial drug prescription event, disease prevalence/risk should be high, then after crossing the initial prescription time, disease prevalence/risk should drop. This would help demonstrate the efficacy of the drug.

Some points to remember:
1) Each medical record maybe unique in timespan. 
2) The first prescription event of a particular drug will happen at different times across the record set. 
3) Some records may have no medical events before the drug was prescribed (as all the diseases of interest feel after the drug prescription of interest).
4) The number of medical events either before or after the first prescription of the drug may be sparsely populated (making binning by time very difficult) or richly populated.

Is there a name for this kind of analysis? I am using R. Any suggestions are very welcome.

Comment: I'm not sure what you ask.  You have a hypothesis: that, after a drug/intervention is prescribed, does 'length of remission' increase.  At best this a classic regression; at worst it feels like a log regression.  So,setting t=0 based on that isn't wrong: your question is "what happens after pharmaceutical intervention".

Comment: Using before-after is not appropriate for determining whether an intervention works. In the absence of randomization, you may want to look at propensity scores (or structural equation models), i.e. Looking for patients that are 'similar', but did not receive the intervention.

Comment: Thank you, Björn. Those suggestions are very helpful and just what I needed.